# how do you implement a text field control in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how do you implement a text field control in React.js
using one of the two functions below to get the label list by keyword. Do not modify the provided functions.

```
function getLabels(keyword) {
    const allLabels = ['NextActions', 'Someday_Actions', 'Costco', 'Alexa'];
  const result = allLabels
    .filter(function(x) {
      return x.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  return result;
}

// or this synchronous api
function getLabelsAsync(keyword) {
    const result = getLabels(keyword);
  const delay = Math.random() * 800 + 200; // delay 200~1000ms
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay, result);
  });
}
```

Comment: Is this interview question? Not quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: here are the instructions https://jsfiddle.net/hxuedt91/

Comment: This is way to broad to answer with code, I can only give you hints, you can use 3 approaches, first use content editable on some div, second use hidden input and fake caret, and third is to use visible input and div before if user type @ and you find the word you add text before @ and tag to div before the input and clear the input ready for next value. I think that the most robust version is hidden input or textarea where you can handle the input. You can even use existing library for fake caret, but I'm not sure if there is one in React, maybe you will need to use JS or jQuery lib.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a controlled component to do it. You need to attach the component state to the input's value and create a method to handle every char the user enters on it.

More details here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer, if you've look at the jsfiddle in comment, the question is how to show dropdown when user write @ and insert color tag instead of selected name.